# Kubernetes resource requests/limits based on time plan

Tags: kubernetes

We can define memory and cpu requests/limits for pods, it is not a problem. Is it possible to define different memory and cpu requests/limits based on time plan? I think about something like that:

```
8AM - 8PM
 - CPU request 0.5, limit 2
 - RAM request 1Gi, limit 2Gi

8:01PM - 7:59AM
 - CPU request 0.1, limit 0.5
 - RAM request 500Mi, limit 1Gi
```

It can help us with tuning of performance based on e.g. high performance real-time processing during the day and lower performance the same pods during the night. Did you solve similar challenge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not something supported by kubernetes core.

This has been discussed many times ([here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/50569) or [there](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/49931) for example)

I can see two ways of solving this challenge :

- Using a `cronJob` and an image that embeds a `kubectl` binary to patch up/down your ressources

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v2alpha1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: patch-memory
spec:
  schedule: "0 8 * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: scale
            image: <your-repo>/kubectl:<tag>
            command:
            - kubectl.sh
            - kubectl
            - patch
            - deployment
            - <your deployment>
            - --patch 
            - '{"spec": {"template": {"spec": {"containers": [{"name": "<your container>": {"resources": {"requests": {"memory": "XXXMi" }}}}]}}}}'
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

- Using a custom controler like [this one](https://github.com/amelbakry/kube-schedule-scaler) or [this one](https://github.com/maheshrayas/kube-saver) or others you can find online. I have no experience using those projects myself.

You could also consider using [Horizontal Pod Autoscaling](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/)  : This  allows you to add more `pod` on a `deployment` or `statefulsets` based on resources usage.

On another hand, you could also use [VPA](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler). This will dynamically set resources requests/limits on your workload based on their resources usage - not in a cron style like you mentioned

Comment: it seems that similar request was open in 2017, nice.

Comment: horizontal pod scaling is useful, but I am focusing on tuning performance in bigger detail, but it is really very useful answ.

Comment: Did you had a look at [VPA](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler) ?
This allows a dynamic resources request/limit, but based on usage and not on a cron AFAIK

Comment: VPA seems very useful